# Regex Group Replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So I'm trying to do a string replace and something is happening that I wouldn't expect to happen and wanted to see if someone could shed some light on it.

I'm trying to do a regex replace where I replace '| ' if it is present. I'm using a group matching and the question mark to get it done, but for some reason it's replacing just spaces as well.

```
$str = 'x x';
$str = preg_replace('/(| )?/','',$str);
echo $str; // Echoes out 'xx' whereas it should return 'x x'
```

But when I replace a space with a carret I get:

```
$str = 'x^x';
$str = preg_replace('/(|^)?/','',$str);
echo $str; // Echoes out 'x^x' as expected
```

Is there some special thing with spaces that I'm not remembering? Or should this just work?

I tried the following:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(|\s)?/','',$str);
$str = preg_replace('/(|[ ])?/','',$str);
```

And both of them are also giving the inaccurate results. Thoughts?

Comment: Escape the pipe with a backslash: `\|`

Comment: Realized this 2 seconds after posting #facepalm Forgot a bar needs escaping

Comment: You should post that as and answer to your question and then accept it for points.

Comment: I'm waiting for @Jerry to add it as an answer so that he can get credit as he was technically the first person to properly answer... Don't want to take away points where they are deserved =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, didn't know you were waiting for me xD

As per comment, you should escape the pipe with a backslash: `\|`.

The `|` (pipe) is a special character in regex and means 'or', so that your regex were matching either 'nothing' or 'space' in the first one and either nothing or caret `^` in the second one.

Comment: Lol no worries =) I guess I should have mentioned it =D Wanted to give you the points since you were able to answer the question in a super fast amount of time.